# Do any .net languages expose 'methodof' or 'fieldof'

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, typeof

So c# exposes the `typeof` keyword which gives us strong typed access to a Type

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);
```

However it does not give us access to `methodof` or `fieldof`. Which would effectively look like this.

```
var method = methodof(MyClass.MyMethod);
var getProperty = methodof(MyClass.get_MyProperty)
var setProperty = methodof(MyClass.set_MyProperty)
var field = fieldof(MyClass.myField);
```

Do any of the **other languages** expose this functionality?

**Note: posting c# reflection code is not a valid answer to this question**

Comment: [In Foof We Trust](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx) by Eric Lippert. I'm not aware of any language that has taken on the challenges that he outlines in there. The main challenge is - how do you deal with overloaded methods?

Comment: I'd say, that while you use the name of a class `MyClass` with `typeof`, there is no equivalent to what you call here `MyClass.MyMethod`, etc. Except it's string name of course

Comment: .Net Reflector showed such things in decompiled code, e.g. `internal static MethodBase _2 = methodof(SomeClass.SomeMethod);`

Answer (score -1):

If you are generating the IL yourself then it is possible.  What typeof(T) does is hardcode the runtime type handle with ldtoken instruction and then calls  Type.GetTypeFromHandle.  When I generate IL I generate equivelent all the time.  Here is some utility method from some code I wrote

```
/// <summary>
/// Pushes the specified member onto the evaluation stack.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="generator">The generator.</param>
/// <param name="member">The member.</param>
public static void EmitLoadMemberInfo(this ILGenerator generator, MemberInfo member)
{
    switch (member.MemberType)
    {
        case MemberTypes.Method:
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, member as MethodInfo);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(MethodBase).GetMethod("GetMethodFromHandle", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new[] { typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle) }, null));
            break;
        case MemberTypes.TypeInfo:
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, member as Type);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static));
            break;
        case MemberTypes.Field:
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, member as FieldInfo);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(FieldInfo).GetMethod("GetFieldFromHandle", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static));
            break;
        case MemberTypes.Constructor:
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, member as ConstructorInfo);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(MethodBase).GetMethod("GetMethodFromHandle", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new[] { typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle) }, null));
            break;

        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported token type.");
    }
}
```

I should also mention there are some mocking frameworks that kinda support that.  I put an example an another post due to size

Answer (score -1):

sorry posted another response due to size.  A lot of mocking frameworks I have used before use this approach.  Basically a method gets passed in and they look for call to what they are mocking.   Here is a sloppy example I coded up.  Should be able to handle overloads.  Not really the same as typeof since like I mentioned in other post a typeof is turned into an ldtoken and call to GetTypeFromRuntimeHandle

```
class Program
{


    static void Main()
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        ConstructorInfo programConstructor = OfUtil.ConstructorOf(() => new Program());
        FieldInfo instanceField = OfUtil.FieldOf(() => program.Field);
        MethodInfo method = OfUtil.MethodOf(() => program.MethodTest(10));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public Program()
    {
    }

    public static int StaticField;
    public int Field;
    public int PropertyTest { get; set; }
    public static int PropertyStatic { get; set; }

    public void MethodTest()
    {
    }

    public void MethodTest(int x)
    {
    }

    public static void StaticMethodTest()
    {
    }
}

public static class OfUtil
{
    private static Dictionary<RuntimeMethodHandle, MemberInfo> cache = new Dictionary<RuntimeMethodHandle, MemberInfo>();

    public static MethodInfo MethodOf(Action action)
    {
        MethodInfo method = MemberOf(action, OpCodes.Call, OpCodes.Callvirt) as MethodInfo;
        return method;
    }

    public static MethodInfo MethodOf<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        MethodInfo method = MemberOf(func, OpCodes.Call, OpCodes.Callvirt) as MethodInfo;
        return method;
    }

    public static ConstructorInfo ConstructorOf<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        ConstructorInfo constructor = MemberOf(func, OpCodes.Newobj, OpCodes.Initobj) as ConstructorInfo;
        return constructor;
    }

    public static FieldInfo FieldOf<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        FieldInfo field = MemberOf(func, OpCodes.Ldfld, OpCodes.Ldflda) as FieldInfo;
        return field;
    }


    private static MemberInfo MemberOf(Delegate action, params OpCode[] ops)
    {
        MemberInfo info = null;
        if (cache.TryGetValue(action.Method.MethodHandle, out info))
        {
            return info;
        }

        ILReader reader = new ILReader(action.Method);
        foreach (ILInstruction instruction in reader.Instructions)
        {
            if (ops.Any(x => x == instruction.Op))
            {
                info = instruction.Data as MemberInfo;
                cache[action.Method.MethodHandle] = info;
                return info;
            }
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Did not find a member.");
    }
}

public interface IILReaderProvider
{
    byte[] GetMethodBody();

    FieldInfo ResolveField(int metadataToken);
    MemberInfo ResolveMember(int metadataToken);

    MethodBase ResolveMethod(int metadataToken);
    byte[] ResolveSignature(int metadataToken);

    string ResolveString(int metadataToken);
    Type ResolveType(int metadataToken);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ILInstruction
{
    private readonly OpCode operationCode; // 40.  56-64.  The entire structure is very big.  maybe do array lookup for opcode instead.

    private readonly byte[] instructionRawData;

    private readonly object instructionData;

    private readonly int instructionAddress;

    private readonly int index;

    internal ILInstruction(OpCode code, byte[] instructionRawData, int instructionAddress, object instructionData, int index)
    {
        this.operationCode = code;
        this.instructionRawData = instructionRawData;
        this.instructionAddress = instructionAddress;
        this.instructionData = instructionData;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public OpCode Op
    {
        get
        {
            return this.operationCode;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the raw data.
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] RawData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.instructionRawData;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the data.
    /// </summary>
    public object Data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.instructionData;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the address of the instruction.
    /// </summary>
    public int Address
    {
        get
        {
            return this.instructionAddress;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the index of the instruction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The index of the instruction.
    /// </value>
    public int InstructionIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return this.index;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value as integer
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The data value.</value>
    public int DataValue
    {
        get
        {
            int value = 0;
            if (this.Data != null)
            {
                if (this.Data is byte)
                {
                    value = (byte)this.Data;
                }
                else if (this.Data is short)
                {
                    value = (short)this.Data;
                }
                else if (this.Data is int)
                {
                    value = (int)this.Data;
                }
            }

            return value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the length of the instructions and operands.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The length.</value>
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Op.Size + (this.RawData == null ? 0 : this.RawData.Length);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="System.String"/> that represents this instance.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendFormat("0x{0:x4} {1,-10}", this.Address, this.Op.Name);

        if (this.Data != null)
        {
            builder.Append(this.Data.ToString());
        }

        if (this.RawData != null && this.RawData.Length > 0)
        {
            builder.Append(" [0x");
            for (int i = this.RawData.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                builder.Append(this.RawData[i].ToString("x2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }

            builder.Append(']');
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads IL instructions from a byte stream.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Allows generated code to be viewed without debugger or enabled debug assemblies.</remarks>
public sealed class ILReader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The _instruction lookup.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Lazy<Dictionary<short, OpCode>> instructionLookup = new Lazy<Dictionary<short, OpCode>>(ILReader.GetLookupTable, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    /// <summary>
    /// The IL reader provider.
    /// </summary>
    private IILReaderProvider intermediateLanguageProvider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ILReader"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="method">
    /// The method.
    /// </param>
    public ILReader(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
        }

        this.intermediateLanguageProvider = ILReader.CreateILReaderProvider(method);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instructions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The instructions.</value>
    public IEnumerable<ILInstruction> Instructions
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] instructionBytes = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.GetMethodBody();
            int instructionIndex = 0, startAddress;
            for (int position = 0; position < instructionBytes.Length; )
            {
                startAddress = position;
                short operationData = instructionBytes[position];
                if (IsInstructionPrefix(operationData))
                {
                    operationData = (short)((operationData << 8) | instructionBytes[++position]);
                }

                position++;

                OpCode code;
                if (!instructionLookup.Value.TryGetValue(operationData, out code))
                {
                    throw new InvalidProgramException(string.Format("0x{0:X2} is not a valid op code.", operationData));
                }

                int dataSize = GetSize(code.OperandType);
                byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(instructionBytes, position, data, 0, dataSize);
                object objData = this.GetData(code, data);
                position += dataSize;

                if (code.OperandType == OperandType.InlineSwitch)
                {
                    dataSize = (int)objData;
                    int[] labels = new int[dataSize];
                    for (int index = 0; index < labels.Length; index++)
                    {
                        labels[index] = BitConverter.ToInt32(instructionBytes, position);
                        position += 4;
                    }

                    objData = labels;
                }

                yield return new ILInstruction(code, data, startAddress, objData, instructionIndex);
                instructionIndex++;
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the IL reader provider.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">The MethodInfo object that represents the method to read..</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The ILReader provider.
    /// </returns>
    private static IILReaderProvider CreateILReaderProvider(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        IILReaderProvider reader = DynamicILReaderProvider.Create(methodInfo);
        if (reader != null)
        {
            return reader;
        }

        return new ILReaderProvider(methodInfo);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks to see if the IL instruction is a prefix indicating the length of the instruction is two bytes long.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The IL instruction as a byte.</param>
    /// <remarks>IL instructions can either be 1 or 2 bytes.</remarks>
    /// <returns>True if this IL instruction is a prefix indicating the instruction is two bytes long.</returns>
    private static bool IsInstructionPrefix(short value)
    {
        return ((value & OpCodes.Prefix1.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix1.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix2.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix2.Value)
                    || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix3.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix3.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix4.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix4.Value)
                    || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix5.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix5.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix6.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix6.Value)
                    || ((value & OpCodes.Prefix7.Value) == OpCodes.Prefix7.Value) || ((value & OpCodes.Prefixref.Value) == OpCodes.Prefixref.Value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The get lookup table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A dictionary of IL instructions.
    /// </returns>
    private static Dictionary<short, OpCode> GetLookupTable()
    {
        // Might be better to do an array lookup.  Use a seperate arrary for instructions without a prefix and array for each prefix.
        Dictionary<short, OpCode> lookupTable = new Dictionary<short, OpCode>();
        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            OpCode code = (OpCode)field.GetValue(null);
            lookupTable.Add(code.Value, code);
        }

        return lookupTable;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the size of a operand.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operandType">Defines the type of operand.</param>
    /// <returns>The size in bytes of the operand type.</returns>
    private static int GetSize(OperandType operandType)
    {
        switch (operandType)
        {
            case OperandType.InlineNone:
                return 0;
            case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget:
            case OperandType.ShortInlineI:
            case OperandType.ShortInlineVar:
                return 1;
            case OperandType.InlineVar:
                return 2;
            case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
            case OperandType.InlineField:
            case OperandType.InlineI:
            case OperandType.InlineMethod:
            case OperandType.InlineSig:
            case OperandType.InlineString:
            case OperandType.InlineSwitch:
            case OperandType.InlineTok:
            case OperandType.InlineType:
            case OperandType.ShortInlineR:
                return 4;
            case OperandType.InlineI8:
            case OperandType.InlineR:
                return 8;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    private object GetData(OpCode code, byte[] rawData)
    {
        object data = null;
        switch (code.OperandType)
        {
            case OperandType.InlineField:
                data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveField(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineSwitch:
                data = BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0);

                break;
            case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
            case OperandType.InlineI:
                data = BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0);
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineI8:
                data = BitConverter.ToInt64(rawData, 0);
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineMethod:
                data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveMethod(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineR:
                data = BitConverter.ToDouble(rawData, 0);
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineSig:
                data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveSignature(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineString:
                data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveString(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineTok:
            case OperandType.InlineType:
                data = this.intermediateLanguageProvider.ResolveType(BitConverter.ToInt32(rawData, 0));
                break;
            case OperandType.InlineVar:
                data = BitConverter.ToInt16(rawData, 0);
                break;
            case OperandType.ShortInlineVar:
            case OperandType.ShortInlineI:
            case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget:
                data = rawData[0];
                break;
            case OperandType.ShortInlineR:
                data = BitConverter.ToSingle(rawData, 0);
                break;
        }

        return data;
    }
}

internal class DynamicILReaderProvider : IILReaderProvider
{
    public const int TypeRidPrefix = 0x02000000;

    public const int MethodRidPrefix = 0x06000000;

    public const int FieldRidPrefix = 0x04000000;

    public static readonly Type RuntimeDynamicMethodType;

    private static readonly FieldInfo fileLengthField = typeof(ILGenerator).GetField("m_length", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    private static readonly FieldInfo IntermediateLanguageBytesField = typeof(ILGenerator).GetField("m_ILStream", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    private static readonly MethodInfo bakeByteArrayMethod = typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("BakeByteArray", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    private static readonly PropertyInfo dynamicScopeIndexor;

    private static readonly FieldInfo dynamicScopeField;

    private static readonly Type genericMethodInfoType;

    private static readonly FieldInfo genericMethodHandleField;

    private static readonly FieldInfo genericMethodContextField;

    private static readonly Type varArgMethodType;

    private static readonly FieldInfo varArgMethodMethod;

    private static readonly Type genericFieldInfoType;

    private static readonly FieldInfo genericFieldInfoHandle;        

    private static readonly FieldInfo genericFieldInfoContext;

    private static readonly FieldInfo ownerField;

    private object dynamicScope;

    private ILGenerator generator;

    static DynamicILReaderProvider()
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        dynamicScopeIndexor = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicScope").GetProperty("Item", bindingFlags);
        dynamicScopeField = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicILGenerator").GetField("m_scope", bindingFlags);

        varArgMethodType = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.VarArgMethod");
        varArgMethodMethod = varArgMethodType.GetField("m_method", bindingFlags);

        genericMethodInfoType = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.GenericMethodInfo");
        genericMethodHandleField = genericMethodInfoType.GetField("m_methodHandle", bindingFlags);
        genericMethodContextField = genericMethodInfoType.GetField("m_context", bindingFlags);

        genericFieldInfoType = Type.GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.GenericFieldInfo", false);
        if (genericFieldInfoType != null)
        {
            genericFieldInfoHandle = genericFieldInfoType.GetField("m_fieldHandle", bindingFlags);
            genericFieldInfoContext = genericFieldInfoType.GetField("m_context", bindingFlags);
        }
        else
        {
            genericFieldInfoHandle = genericFieldInfoContext = null;
        }

        RuntimeDynamicMethodType = typeof(DynamicMethod).GetNestedType("RTDynamicMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        ownerField = RuntimeDynamicMethodType.GetField("m_owner", bindingFlags);
    }

    private DynamicILReaderProvider(DynamicMethod method)
    {
        this.Method = method;
        this.generator = method.GetILGenerator();
        this.dynamicScope = dynamicScopeField.GetValue(this.generator);
    }

    public DynamicMethod Method { get; private set; }

    internal object this[int token]
    {
        get
        {
            return dynamicScopeIndexor.GetValue(this.dynamicScope, new object[] { token });
        }
    }

    public static DynamicILReaderProvider Create(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
        }

        DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = method as DynamicMethod;
        if (dynamicMethod != null)
        {
            return new DynamicILReaderProvider(dynamicMethod);
        }

        Type methodType = method.GetType();
        if (RuntimeDynamicMethodType.IsAssignableFrom(methodType))
        {
            return new DynamicILReaderProvider(ownerField.GetValue(method) as DynamicMethod);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public byte[] GetMethodBody()
    {
        byte[] data = null;
        ILGenerator ilgen = this.Method.GetILGenerator();

        try
        {
            data = (byte[])bakeByteArrayMethod.Invoke(ilgen, null) ?? new byte[0];
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException)
        {
            int length = (int)fileLengthField.GetValue(ilgen);
            data = new byte[length];
            Array.Copy((byte[])IntermediateLanguageBytesField.GetValue(ilgen), data, length);
        }

        return data;
    }

    public FieldInfo ResolveField(int metadataToken)
    {
        object tokenValue = this[metadataToken];
        if (tokenValue is RuntimeFieldHandle)
        {
            return FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle((RuntimeFieldHandle)tokenValue);
        }

        if (tokenValue.GetType() == DynamicILReaderProvider.genericFieldInfoType)
        {
            return FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle(
                (RuntimeFieldHandle)genericFieldInfoHandle.GetValue(tokenValue),
                (RuntimeTypeHandle)genericFieldInfoContext.GetValue(tokenValue));
        }

        return null;
    }

    public MemberInfo ResolveMember(int metadataToken)
    {
        if ((metadataToken & TypeRidPrefix) != 0)
        {
            return this.ResolveType(metadataToken);
        }

        if ((metadataToken & MethodRidPrefix) != 0)
        {
            return this.ResolveMethod(metadataToken);
        }

        if ((metadataToken & FieldRidPrefix) != 0)
        {
            return this.ResolveField(metadataToken);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public MethodBase ResolveMethod(int metadataToken)
    {
        object tokenValue = this[metadataToken];
        DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = tokenValue as DynamicMethod;
        if (dynamicMethod != null)
        {
            return dynamicMethod;
        }

        if (tokenValue is RuntimeMethodHandle)
        {
            return MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle((RuntimeMethodHandle)this[metadataToken]);
        }

        if (tokenValue.GetType() == DynamicILReaderProvider.genericFieldInfoType)
        {
            return MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(
                (RuntimeMethodHandle)genericMethodHandleField.GetValue(tokenValue),
                (RuntimeTypeHandle)genericMethodContextField.GetValue(tokenValue));
        }

        if (tokenValue.GetType() == DynamicILReaderProvider.varArgMethodType)
        {
            return DynamicILReaderProvider.varArgMethodMethod.GetValue(tokenValue) as MethodInfo;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public byte[] ResolveSignature(int metadataToken)
    {
        return this[metadataToken] as byte[];
    }
    public string ResolveString(int metadataToken)
    {
        return this[metadataToken] as string;
    }

    public Type ResolveType(int metadataToken)
    {
        return Type.GetTypeFromHandle((RuntimeTypeHandle)this[metadataToken]);
    }
}

internal class ILReaderProvider : IILReaderProvider
{
    public ILReaderProvider(MethodInfo method)
    {
        this.Method = method;
        this.MethodBody = method.GetMethodBody();
        this.MethodModule = method.Module;
    }

    public MethodInfo Method { get; private set; }

    public MethodBody MethodBody { get; private set; }

    public Module MethodModule { get; private set; }

    public byte[] GetMethodBody()
    {
        return this.MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray();
    }

    public FieldInfo ResolveField(int metadataToken)
    {
        return this.MethodModule.ResolveField(metadataToken);
    }

    public MemberInfo ResolveMember(int metadataToken)
    {
        return this.MethodModule.ResolveMember(metadataToken);
    }

    public MethodBase ResolveMethod(int metadataToken)
    {
        return this.MethodModule.ResolveMethod(metadataToken);
    }

    public byte[] ResolveSignature(int metadataToken)
    {
        return this.MethodModule.ResolveSignature(metadataToken);
    }

    public string ResolveString(int metadataToken)
    {
        return this.MethodModule.ResolveString(metadataToken);
    }

    public Type ResolveType(int metadataToken)
    {

        return this.MethodModule.ResolveType(metadataToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of the workarounds but the question is not about c#